# Replace Function with "," in string in access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

Suppose I have:

```
Str1 = "Corpse"
Str2 = "Co, p"
```

Now I want to use "Replace Function" and color "Co" and "p" in "Corpse". Can I do this?

```
x = Str1
y = Str2(?)
z = "<font color=#ee00ee>" + y + "</font>"
Replace(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Maybe it is better you explain your environment and what you are trying to achieve.No one can help you with this code except say: "No, you can't." But I guess you want something else altogether since your question has not much to do with the coloring part. So: what do you need this for? Where is the color supposed to appear? a Form? an HTML file you are printing to?

Comment: For solving my problem, I used two fileds instead of one filed and separated "co" and "p". Then I used Replace Function. I recived true answer. I use one form and several textboxes.